# XNA 4.0 Graphics Device Error

Tags: graphics, device, xna-4.0

I know that the way the declaration of the graphics device is suppose to look in the main Game1() constructor is:

```
 GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;

 graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
```

then you can use stuff like:

```
 graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1366;
```

But if I declare the same inside a separate class, what do I fill in for "this"?

```
 GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;

 graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(?);
```

EDIT:

After modifying everything as you said, I now get a error that sends me to this line of code:

```
     /// <summary>
    /// Event handler for when the Play Game menu entry is selected.
    /// </summary>
    void PlayGameMenuEntrySelected(object sender, PlayerIndexEventArgs e, Game game)
    {
        LoadingScreen.Load(ScreenManager, true, e.PlayerIndex,
                           new GameplayScreen(game));
    }
```

This program is the menu sample you can get from Microsoft, heavily modified of course, this is the code that executes when you hit enter on the main menu screen with "Play Game" highlighted. I guess the problem is passing the variable.

Edit 2:

I fixed the code I think but now it sent me to this line and I don't know how to edit it.

```
 playGameMenuEntry.Selected += PlayGameMenuEntrySelected;
```

Comment: Where are you declaring LoadingScreen? I can't get to the apphub samples at the moment. I'll make this easy: go to that line in VS, put your cursor on `LoadingScreen`, right-click and select "Go to definition."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a reference to your Game instance. I'd just pass it to your new class constructor.

For example, if you want to move the `GraphicsDeviceManager` instance into a separate class, `Foo`,

```
/// <summary>
/// This is the main type for your game
/// </summary>
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    private Foo _foo;

    public Game1()
    {
        _foo = new Foo(this);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_foo != null)
        {
            _foo.Dispose();
            _foo = null;
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

}

public class Foo : IDisposable
{
    private Game _game;
    private GraphicsDeviceManager _graphics;
    private SpriteBatch _spriteBatch;

    public Foo(Game game)
    {
        _game = game;
        _game.Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

        _graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(_game);
        _spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(_game.GraphicsDevice);
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!_spriteBatch.IsDisposed)
        {
            _spriteBatch.Dispose();
            _spriteBatch = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

It's important to properly dispose of a lot of XNA objects (otherwise, you get memory leaks). See Foo.Dispose() and the Game1.Dispose() override above.

Comment: Ok, I passed it like "public GameplayScreen(Game1)" but is says I am missing an identifier.

Comment: You might want to read up on some C# basics... add the relevant code snippet to your post. The line `public GameplayScreen(Game1)` isn't valid C# in any context.

Comment: Thank you very much, now where I would use Content I would use _game.Content, _graphics for graphics and _spriteBatch for spriteBatch, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I also added some `Dispose()` code to the example. A LOT of XNA assets - effects, spritebatch, models, etc, have to be disposed of when your app shuts down. If you don't, it'll leak memory and eventually the system can crash quite unceremoniously.

Comment: Do you have Skype? It would be easier to talk than comment back and forth.

Comment: Error 1 No overload for 'PlayGameMenuEntrySelected' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler<GameStateManagement.PlayerIndexEventArgs>' C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\Dropbox\Sleyser Games\Dave's Programming\Sleyser1\Sleyser1\Sleyser1\Screens\MainMenuScreen.cs 37 43 Sleyser1

Comment: Here is a link to the sample: http://create.msdn.com/downloads/?id=77&filename=GSMSample_4_0_WIN_XBOX.zip